# Get Day, Month, and Year from Time in Go Language

Tags: date, datetime, go

I have an object like this:

```
type searchObj struct {
    symbol string
    dataType string
    fromDate time.Time
    toDate time.Time
}
```

I want to be able to parse out the day, month, and year from the fromDate and the toDate. How can I do this? Is there a better type to use like (Date) because I do not need the time piece of it?

so I want to be able to pass a date like this 02/19/2016 and be able to get data.Day = 19, date.Month = 02, date.Year = 2016.

I was trying something like this:

```
search.fromDate.Date.Month
search.fromDate.Date.Day
search.fromDate.Date.Year
```

This is an example of what I am currently using to create the searchObj:

```
time.Date(2009, time.November, 10, 23, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
```

I am new to Go and thank you for the help!

Comment: What about the `Month()`, `Day()` and `Year()` methods on `time.Time`?

Comment: @JimB: That's expensive. Use [func (Time) Date](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Date)

Comment: @peterSO, yeah, I didn't check the docs myself ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the methods you're looking for exist on the `time.Time` type. You can just do;

```
year := fromDate.Year()
month := fromDate.Month()
day := fromDate.Day()
```

EDIT:
I suppose it would be more concise to use time.Date like so;

```
year, month, day := fromDate.Date()
```

Comment: That's what i am looking for. Thanks, sorry for the bad question.

Comment: @user3788671 that's nbd. It may be obvious for people familiar with the package/type but if it's not on SO already then there is value in asking it.

Answer (score 11):

With the accepted method, if you need the month **number** you can simply cast the Month object to int since it's an enum:

```
year, month, day := time.Now().Date()
log.Printf("%v-%v-%v", year, int(month), day)
```

Answer (score 10):

The `time` type also has [`Date()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Date) method which returns the year, month and day of the time in single call.